# How to change the camera model when using image_pipeline?

Tags: calibration, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, camera-calibration, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I do some binocular camera calibration tests with image_pipeline. For some reasons, I can not see the video in the image_pipeline/Tutorials page. I have to ask questions there.
1, How can I cange the camera model? You know that diferent cameras should choose the appropriate one. Further, I want to know all the models that image_pipeline supports.
2, How can I get the baseline after I do the calibration? I just get 3 files: left.yaml, right.yaml and ost.txt. I don't see the extrinsic parameters, which I mean a matrix to show transformation relationship between double cameras. Is there some commend to add it into the outputs?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335219/how-to-change-the-camera-model-when-using-image_pipeline?/) by [YancenBOB](https://answers.ros.org/users/44257/yancenbob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2019-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `PinholeCameraModel` from `image_geometry` supports either the 5 parameter "Plumb Bob" model or the 8 parameter "Rational Polynomial" model.  This is specified in [REP 104](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0104.html#alternate-distortion-models), and implemented using `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap` in the [image_geometry package](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/blob/0bbebb73bea65eca856e732b919439853a04986b/image_geometry/src/pinhole_camera_model.cpp#L453).

The extrinsic calibration should be included in either the `left.yaml` or `right.yaml` file via the `R` and `P` parameters in the copmuted camera information.  From the [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo documentation](https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html):

```
# Projection/camera matrix
#     [fx'  0  cx' Tx]
# P = [ 0  fy' cy' Ty]
#     [ 0   0   1   0]
# ...snip...
# For a stereo pair, the fourth column [Tx Ty 0]' is related to the
#  position of the optical center of the second camera in the first
#  camera's frame. We assume Tz = 0 so both cameras are in the same
#  stereo image plane. The first camera always has Tx = Ty = 0. For
#  the right (second) camera of a horizontal stereo pair, Ty = 0 and
#  Tx = -fx' * B, where B is the baseline between the cameras.
```

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2019-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YancenBOB](https://answers.ros.org/users/44257/yancenbob/) on 2019-10-11**:
Thank you! I have got the baseline. For the camera model, I have another question that dose image_pipeline only support Pinhole camera model and Plumb Bob distortion model? For other calibration tools I see some like equidistant model and so on. I need to use different tools to double check the result.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2019-10-14**:
Yes, I believe that those are the only two it supports.  At the time that this software was written, these were the only models that OpenCV supported.  I believe in recent years, OpenCV has added support for a fisheye model as well, but `image_geometry` has not been updated to accomodate this.

**Comment by [YancenBOB](https://answers.ros.org/users/44257/yancenbob/) on 2019-10-15**:
Thanks for your help! Thank you!